# not exact image copy after copying from url

Tags: php, file-upload, file-get-contents

I am using function with code below to copy image from url to my web directory, but I don't know why some images are not copied in 100%.

Here is copy of wrong image in my web directory http://www.aligatoor.pl/uploads/deals/2632b3802e8ed7abe83788dab605bbf7.jpg

and here the original image http://infobuzer.pl/img/r4d3k/voucher/50e35a84c9038.jpg

```
function upload_file($file_path)
{
    $deal_img_data=file_get_contents($file_path);

    $file_name=md5($file_path).".jpg";

    if(!file_exists($file_name))
    {
        $file=fopen($file_name,"w+");

        fwrite($file,$deal_img_data);
    }
}
```

I have also tried with CURL but it is still not copying some images properly.

CURL code:

```
$ch = curl_init ($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
$raw=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$saveto=md5($url).".jpg";
if(file_exists($saveto)){
    unlink($saveto);
}
$fp = fopen($saveto,'x');
fwrite($fp, $raw);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: while not just file_put_contents instead of fopen/fwrite?

Comment: You probably just need to specify "wb+" as the flags. b means binary mode. That might be the reason. It might think it is a text file.

Comment: "wb+" and file_put_contents doesn't work to

Comment: I have also tried with curl and there is still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your function works fine

Just delete the old image and try to download it again.

also add:

```
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what the reason for your problem, but I faced similar issues with file handling and I solved it using this approach:

```
  if( $handle =fopen($filename, "wb+") ){
    if(flock($handle, LOCK_EX))
    {
      fseek($handle, 0); 
      ftruncate($handle, 0); 

      fwrite($handle, $newcontent);

      fflush($handle); 
      flock($handle, LOCK_UN); 
    }
    fclose($handle); 
  }
```

[FLOCK()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php)

EDIT: For handling images its better to use image functions such as [imagejpeg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) and [imagecreatefromjpeg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) for better security and accurate result.

EXAMPLE:

```
  $im = @imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
  if(is_bool($im)){
   die("Invalid Image detected!");
  }
  else{

    if(!imagejpeg($im, $newpath)){
     die("Image not saved!");
    }
    else{
     die("Image saved!");
    }  
  }
```

Edit2:Add this instead of using file_get_contents()

```
<?php

$handle = fopen($file_path, "rb");
$deal_img_data = stream_get_contents($handle);
fclose($handle);

?>
```

Comment: which part you used? what error you got? can you provide your trial?

Comment: I have tried this first your code and there isn't any error, just still not exact copy of image. I have also tried with CURL and it still some image are alright and some not.

Comment: use updated section, or it might be your network connection, cache, or hosting system issue.

Comment: still the same problem..i have got my own dedicated server, so if u know what can cause this problem from server configurate then let me know please. I don't think so that it is a network connection as what I found is this that the problem is always with the same images.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way how to do it, so if any one has got similar problem to my, he can try using this function:

```
function grab_image($url){
    $ch = curl_init ($url);
    $saveto = md5($url).".jpg";
    $fp = fopen($saveto,'wb');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try adding set_time_limit(0) at the beggining of the function

Comment: Its only a ~50K file, how would this help?

Comment: it may not help, but certainly would rule out the remote possibility that the script is being killed before the file is closed.